# How to check if a day falls between two unknown date in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

Let me explain, I have an employee leave table which has date leave starts and date leave ends what I want is how to check if a day(today) falls between those dates without Knowing date leave starts and date leave ends.

leave table

```
+Emp_id + leave start date + leave end date+
|004    |2013-12-15        |2013-12-29     |      
|004    |2014-01-17        |2014-01-24     |
|004    |2014-11-3         |2014-11-15     |
```

How to check if a day(2014-11-7) falls between leave start date and leave end date

Comment: What do you mean without specifying? Do you mean without knowing the dates yourself or without a query?

Comment: ya with out knowing the dates

Comment: Your question is not clear -- how could one determine if a date stands between two dates *without knowing those two dates*?

Comment: +Emp_id leave start date leave end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  employee_leave
WHERE
  '2014-11-7' BETWEEN leave_start_date AND leave_end_date;
```